# Clear() e SendKeys() num só método

Tags: java, testes, selenium-webdriver

Tenho os métodos `clear` e `sendKeys` e queria `"colapsar"` os dois num só,

```
WebElement user = webdriver.findElement(By.id("username"));
user.clear();
user.sendKeys(username);       
WebElement passw = webdriver.findElement(By.id("password"));
passw.clear();
passw.sendKeys(password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes criar um método novo:

```
public void setNewInputValue(WebElement elem, String value) {
    elem.clear();
    elem.sendKeys(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem 2 opções que eu conheço, mas acredito que a melhor alternativa realmente seja criar um método para a ação, conforme os exemplos abaixo:

```
@Test
public void clearSendTest() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[title='pesquisar']")).sendKeys(Keys.CLEAR, "php");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}

public void clearAfterSend() {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[title='pesquisar']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[title='pesquisar']")).sendKeys("java");
}

@Test
public void clearAfterSendTest() throws InterruptedException {
    clearAfterSend();
}
```